# Make multiples copies of all existing pages in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Say that there are 3 pages in the system, I would like to copy these pages and specify a name, for example:

- Neon (existing)

  - Neon_A
  - Neon_B
- Xenon (existing)

  - Xenon_A
  - Xenon_B
- Argon (existing)

  - Argon_A
  - Argon_B

Is there a [maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Maintenance_scripts) that would work or do I need to create one?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Extension:Duplicator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Duplicator) and then moving the pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maintenance script that would do this, you would need to create one. But I would recommend [making a bot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to do this unless you want to copy history etc.